use SQL query via Power query to inquiry a different excel spreadsheet
I have an excel spreaadsheet (ExcelData.xlsx) that contains a table named "tblTransactions".
I would like to understand if it is possible (and if so, how) to use a SQL query (through Power query) to analyze and manipulate the data contained in the table transaction.
My table has the following headers IdTransaction, TransactionDT, TransactionOperator.
Even a simple select * that returns all the values would be a great result.
I tried to use a file DSN but it did not work. I tried to use the "new query from excel file" but, while I can connect to the file, I do not know if (and how) run my simple query on the connected file.
I am trying to avoid VBA and keep everything within Power Query.
Any help, indication or suggestion is very appreciated!

I'm not sure I understand where SQL comes in. You have data in Excel, You want to query it with Power Query. Can you explain what the SQL query would do?

Substantially I would like to inquiry the tblTransactions from a different spreadsheet through PowerQuery, in the same way I use a DB table (using a SQL query).
The purpose is to manipulate and do calculations on the content of that table using SQL.

You can import Excel data into SQL Server.
You can pull SQL data into Excel via Power Query and combine other data from Excel spreadsheets using Power Query.
But you can't use Power Query in Excel from SQL to get data from an Excel spreadsheet. It's not how this works.
You may want to state the desired outcome first, then you can identify the approach and the tools you need.

If you want to do calculations in SQL, then load the spreadsheet into SQL. But Power query doesn't come into the mix. It doesn't make sense.

That makes sense. Substantially I need to do a gap and island analysis on a certain dataset on a db.
I've been able to figure out how to do it using a SQL query but unfortunately I cannot use the normal SQL server sintax as the database is not a common one and does not accept the SQL server sintax.
What I was thinking is:
I export the entire dataset on excel with a simple query into my table "tblTransactions" and then I use a SQL statement to extract the data from that table in the shape that I need.
Can you think at a different solution?

Import the data into SQL Server using maybe SSIS and and Excel source (or use the wizard). Then you can do gaps and islands analysis using windowing functions. (See Itzik Ben-Gan's articles on it. There are several.)
